# ¿Como puedo serializar los datos de este formulario con este estilo?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

tengo varios formulario como este,

```
 <div id="proveedores" style="display: none;">
                <form id="lineaproveedor">
                    <?php include 'funciones/obras/proveedor/fun_list_proveedor.php'; ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_proveedores">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Descripción</label>
                        <textarea style="resize:none;" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Suministro del proveedor" id="descripcionp" name="descripcionp"></textarea>
                        <div id="err_des" class="alert alert-danger errlogin" style="display:none;">Introduce la descripción del proveedor</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Coste</label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-solid h-auto py-5 px-6" type="number" step="any" id="costep" name="costep" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Coste del Suministro" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 45 && event.charCode <= 57)">
                        <div id="err_horas" class="alert alert-danger errlogin" style="display:none;">Introduce el importe</div>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="altaProveedor();">Dar de Alta</button>
                    </div>
                <form>
            </div>
```

El caso es que cuando recojo con .serialize() en jquery llamando al id, al hacer un alert, sale el form en blanco y me pasa lo mismo en todos, como si no detectara que existe ese id. ¿Alguien puede tener idea de que hago mal?

La serialización:

```
var data = $("#lineaproveedor").serialize();
    alert(data);
    $.ajax(
        {
          type: "POST",
          url: "funciones/obras/proveedor/fun_alta_parte_proveedor.php",
          data:data,
          dataType: "html",
          processData: false,
          contentType:false,
          success:function(res)
            {
                $("#actuPartes").load(" #actuPartes",function(res,status,xhr)
                {
                  if (status=="success")
                  {
                      $("#nueva_linea").modal('hide');
                  }
                });
            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                alert ("Error al conectar con el servidor");
            }
        }
    );
```

Aparentemente, no veo que haya ningún fallo.

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta cómo estás haciendo esta serialización. El código :)

Comment: Corregido, pensaba que la había puesto.

Comment: En el formulario que indicas no hay nada con id `lineasubcontrata`. Puede que sea otro formulario, pero es sólo para descartar cosas y que tu ejemplo sea verificable :)

Comment: Perdón, tenía VCS abierto y copié mal, el caso es que tengo 5 formularios distintos, pero todo lo hago exactamente igual que ahí, la unica forma de serializar es llamando a form, pero me saca todos los campos. Cada formulario tiene un id independiente, pero no sé en que falla, que nunca se serializan.

Comment: El `<form>` está mal cerrado y no sabemos qué hace el script PHP que incluyes, pero incluso así, pruebo y la serialización igual debería entregar los campos que están ahí...

Comment: Pues en [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/s278mjec/) funciona tal cual lo tienes. Ya no sabría si el php que incluyes rompe algo o si la versión de JQuery que tienes es muy vieja...

Comment: No te puedo dar por correcta tu respuesta, pero era eso, el form estaba mal cerrado, y al copiar y pegar en proveedores y subcontratas, por que son lo mismo, me daba ese problema, pero muchas gracias :D

Comment: Jejejeje, no hay lío. De hecho, clasifica como pregunta a cerrar por error tipográfico :D Me alegra que funcionara